# SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image, cropping image using pillow package

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a box coordinates that I want to use to crop image:

The box coordinates are:

```
min_x = 0

max_X = image_width

min_height = 590

max_height = 620
```

The image height and width are: `1450x644`

I tried doing this with PILLOW:

```
cropped_image = ImageOps.crop(image, (0, 620, width, 590))
cropped_image.show()
```

It throws this error:

```
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

I tried inverting the y parameters ( `ImageOps.crop(image, (0, 590, width, 620))`  but it gives the same error

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on [`PIL.ImageOps.crop`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.crop): You specify the number of pixels removed from each side of the image. So, you crop `0` pixels left and right, and 590 pixels from the top, and 24 pixels from the bottom, if I interpret your numbers correctly. Or, simply use [`PIL.Image.crop`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop), which does the same, but in the way, you might have in mind.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you. I should have readed that